# Ansible release with serial: 50% for two different backend in haproxy

Tags: deployment, ansible, haproxy

I have the following configuration in haproxy.

```
backend 1

machine-1 machine-1.com:8080 
machine-2 machine-2.com:8080 
machine-3 machine-3.com:8080 
machine-4 machine-4.com:8080
machine-5 machine-5.com:8080 
machine-6 machine-6.com:8080 
machine-7 machine-7.com:8080 
machine-8 machine-8.com:8080 
machine-9 machine-9.com:8080 
machine-10 machine-10.com:8080 

backend 2
machine-11 machine-11.com:8080 
machine-12 machine-12.com:8080
```

`Serial is set to 50% in ansible rolling deployment`.We also change the state of the machines to maintenance in this window. Thus ansible puts machine 1-6 in maintenance mode in the first go while making 7-12 as maintenance in the second go.

As it puts 7-12 as maintenance in the second go; the backend 2 cluster has no nodes online to take the traffic. This causes a huge number of issues on the application side.

How should I remediate this? I am using ansible 2.0.0.

**EDIT 1**

Two solutions that I can think of

1. Make two releases for two backends
2. replace one machine from 1-6 with one machine in backend 2, say 11.

Looking for solutions other than these. more in the line of using ansible to solve it.

Comment: could you put in a `wait_for` to wait for the first 6 to be online again before moving on?

Comment: @smiller171 That will not help as it will still take machine 7-12 out of haproxy. In process of doing so, leave backend 2 without a machine online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a `host groups` for each backend and run the update for each backend group in a separate run would be IMHO the best solution. If there is no way to do that it is possible to define batch sizes as a [list](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) since Ansible 2.2.

So this should work:

```
- name: test play
  hosts: backend servers.
  serial:
  - 5
  - 1
```